# Docker-Compose Spark Elasticsearch Connection NetworkClient Error

Tags: scala, docker, apache-spark

I cannot find a solution to the error message I'm getting, when running spark-submit within a docker container.

So the overall idea is to generate data via kafka, which have this structure:

```
{'source': 'JFdyGil9YYHU', 'target': 'M4iCWTNB7P9E', 'amount': 5425.76, 'currency': 'EUR'}
```

Then receiving this data in Spark via Scala-script, which is:

```
package com.example.spark

import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
import org.apache.spark.{TaskContext, SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.{OffsetRange, HasOffsetRanges, KafkaUtils}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON

import org.elasticsearch.spark._

object Receiver {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    /** when starting the receiver, broker and topics must be passed.*/
    if (args.length < 2) {
      System.err.println(s"""
        |Usage: DirectReceiver <brokers> <topics>
        |  <brokers> is a list of one or more Kafka brokers
        |  <topics> is a list of one or more kafka topics to consume from
        |
        """.stripMargin)
      System.exit(1)
    }

    val Array(brokers, topics) = args


    /** Create context:
    *   The --master option specifies the master URL for a distributed cluster,
    *   or local to run locally with one thread,
    *   or local[N] to run locally with N threads,
    *   or local[*] to run locally with as many worker threads as logical cores on your machine.
    *   You should start by using local for testing.
    */
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Receiver").setMaster("local[*]")

    /** Whether elasticsearch-hadoop should create an index (if its missing)
    *   when writing data to Elasticsearch or fail.
    *   (default: yes, but specifying anyway for the sake of completeness)
    */
    sparkConf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true")

    /** Define that the context batch interval should take 2 seconds.*/
    //val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2)) // testing alternatives
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))

    // Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
    val topicsSet = topics.split(",").toSet // if there are many
    val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> brokers)
    val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
      ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)

    /** Get the lines.
    *   messages are of format:
    *   (null, {"key": "value", "key": "value, ...})
    *   .map(_._2) takes the second tuple argument
    */
    val lines = messages.map(_._2)

    /** pairs are now: [Ljava.lang.String;@5922fbe4
    *   it is what "toString" function in scala actually returns:
    *   def toString(): String = this.getClass.getName + "@" + this.hashCode.toHexString
    *   [ means it’s an array
    *   L means it can contain references to objects
    *   java.lang.String means all those objects should be instances of java.lang.String
    *   ; is just because Java loves its semicolons
    *
    *   Get rid of all the unneccessary charecters and split the string by comma for further usage.
    */
    val pairs = lines.map(_.stripPrefix("{").stripSuffix("}").replaceAll("\"|\\s", "").split(","))

    /** Getting key-value from the pairs, which are:
    *   key: value
    *    key: value
    *    key: value
    *    ...
    */
    pairs.foreach(arr =>
        arr.map(
            x => Map( x(0).split(":")(0) -> x(0).split(":")(1) )
        ).saveToEs("spark/json-test")
    )
    /* testing
    pairs.foreach(
        arr => arr.foreach( x =>
            //val source = Map(x.map(_.1) -> x.map(_.2))
            //source.foreach(println)
            x => x.foreach(println)
        )
    )*/

    // Start the computation
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

And my docker-compose.yml file is the following:

```
version: '3.7'
services:


# kafka (zookeeper integrated)
  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    build: ./kafka
    environment:
      - KAFKA=localhost:9092
      - ZOOKEEPER=localhost:2181
    expose:
      - 2181
      - 9092
    networks:
      - kaspelki-net

# spark (contains all daemons)
  spark:
    container_name: spark
    build: ./spark
    command: bash
    links:
      - "kafka"
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 7077:7077
      - 6066:6066
      - 4040:4040
    environment:
      - SPARK_MASTER_HOST=spark://localhost:7077
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop/hadoop.env
    tty: true
    expose:
      - 7077
      - 8080
      - 6066
      - 4040
    volumes:
      - ./scripts/spark:/app
    networks:
      - kaspelki-net


# ELK
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    build: ./ELK/elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    expose:
      - 9200
    networks:
      - kaspelki-net


  kibana:
    container_name: kibana
    build: ./ELK/kibana
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    expose:
      - 5601
    networks:
      - kaspelki-net
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch



### --- volumes --- ###
volumes:
  data:
networks:
  kaspelki-net:
    name: kaspelki-net
```

So I'm running "sudo docker-compose up -d" and I can test "localhost:9200" and "localhost:5601" within my browser, which work fine, but when I'm running the container via "sudo docker exec -it spark bash" and try to submit my receiver.jar via:

> spark-submit --master yarn-client --driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///app/receiver/log4j.properties" /app/receiver/building_jar/target/scala-2.10/receiver.jar kafka:9092 test

Then I get this error message:

> 18/12/28 09:05:18 ERROR NetworkClient: Node [127.0.0.1:9200] failed (Connection refused); no other nodes left - aborting...

with some other messages, in which the process exits.
So I understand that somehow the connection fails, but I don't understand WHY :/

Can please somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Spark but somewhere in your config you are trying to connect to `localhost:9200` from one container to another which won't work (this works outside of docker as localhost is your machine, but when each service is running in its own container localhost refers to each container's localhost NOT the host machine).

So change your config when running in docker to reference elastic search using the compose service name (in your case `elasticsearch`) instead of localhost and it should all work - you'll need to add elasticsearch as a `link` in the compose file under the calling service in order to reference it by service name like that (just like you did for kafka as a link under spark).

Comment: Hello @Markoorn, thanks for the reply! I understand now, what the problem is. I tried some variations of configuring the docker-compose file (including the link you suggested), but I don't know how to "reference elastic search using elasticsearch instead of localhost". Feeling kind of stupid - could you give me a hint, how to do that?

Comment: I finally have solved this error by using your answer. I had to add the link as you said and had to remove the ".setMaster(local[*])" from my .scala file. Now I get another error, but this question is solved :) Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems that removing the "local[*]" -master setting leads my spark to not processing anything anymore (it took me a while to realize this, because I worked on an error with the syntax), although I pass --master yarn-client within the spark-submit command. So the problem is still the same and the answer is still correct. The one thing that is missing (for me) is that I somehow still do not get it to work correctly :( If anybody can help - I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Hi @Nin4ikP - Sorry, unfortunately I have no idea how Spark is setup as I have never used it, is there a way to have profiles for different environments? Basically, what you want to achieve is a setup where when running locally you use localhost as the base address, and then when running in docker you would have a different config where it would then rather use the compose service names

Comment: Hey :) Thank you for your help! I'm a bit new to everything in this area. So as far as I understood is everything I need is not local. (I ran a local script for Hello world, but of course I need the tools (Kafka, Spark, Elasticsearch, Kibana) to communicate, so I'm not running any code locally. But I think the problem is that I'm trying to run the code with the yarn-client, since I read something about ppl who had issues with these settings. So I think I will ask another question in a few minutes regarding this problem.Maybe somebody also had it and can answer:) Anyways -Thank you!